# WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Tags: selenium, webdriver

im using:
chrome 43
chromedriver 2.15.322448
remote server on linux ubuntu

It was working fine before, but I killed all chromedriver and google-chrome processes. 
Now im getting :
Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310ec1797c81ea9a2326839860b7d3) on port 31153
Only local connections are allowed.

**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable**

what can be reason ?

Comment: Once refer this: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364012/webdriver-exception-chrome-not-reachable**

Comment: I've dig through all this. No solution.In my case im sure it was working before. Everything should be set up fine, except chrome

Comment: are u using the updated selenium jars?