# Chrome not reachable error message selenium webdriver for chromium application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I am automating a chromium application using selenium webdriver. These are my configuration settings:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--url=application url");
chromeOptions.setBinary("application exe file");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=8000"); WebDriver
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

This code launches the chromium application successfully.  I've confirmed that port 8000 is listening and able to get chromium application object on chrome browser.

But I am getting the exception below:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333243
>   (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 18739 Only local
>   connections are allowed. FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Comment: What's in your @BeforeMethod

Comment: I put all above code in setup method (@BeforeClass)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364012/webdriver-exception-chrome-not-reachable) and what's the chrome version

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am automating chromium application which view is like desktop application (setup is executable file). Do you have any idea chromium application.

Comment: I believe it should be a location at line: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\XYZ\chromedriver.exe");