# Chrome Not Reachable (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use chrome web driver but the error is : chrome not reachable. I have tried using gecko driver for Mozilla Firefox and it is successful but not for chrome. How can i fix this, since i have tried all the suggested solutions. My current

chrome is v59 and
chrome web driver is version 2.9 and
server-standalone 3.4

Any helps would be appreciates.[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRmgF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238031/chrome-not-reachable-when-invoking-selenium-scripts-from-eclipse-ide

Comment: Thanks @ShailendraRathore , i already look at it. And my version is all uptodate.